# Stop recording in vlc pugin

Tags: vlc

I use VLC plugin to show live stream and then record from my server and save it into a file.

when i start record, i choose the time of record and i use it into "--run-time" and the record still to this time, it's ok.

but if i choose a time for record, i can't stop it till it finish the time.

so please, do you have any solution how i can Stop recording in vlc pugin and stop the execution of the command before the finish of the run-time if i need this ?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Mr Hassan, you can do that via TELNET interface.
Basically you set the option -I telnet and --telnet-password in the command you are using to start the VLC (supposing you are using command line). When you want to stop the connection you make a TELNET connection to port 4212 and you are able to stop recording.